# IntelliJ IDEA - How to align fields inside anonymous classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to align/reformat code in my IntelliJ IDEA IDE. But, it's not aligning fields inside anonymous classes. Checkout below example code:

```
public class Hello {
    private int   x   = 1;
    private float xyz = 100F;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");

        (new Thread() {
            private int a = 1;
            private String abc = "alphabet";

            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

> In above code x & xyz fields are aligned properly. But, a & abc fields
> are not aligning. How to solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean they are not aligned? To me, they are perfectly aligned

Comment: @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo really !? x & xyz field's types, names, values are properly aligned in column. But, a & abc fields are not.

Comment: you might have to check the java code formatting settings for anonymous classes

Comment: They are, `a` and `abc` belong to `new Thread()`, therefore, the are indented inside

Comment: @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo Is it really that hard to understand? OP means that "a" and "abc" don't start in the same column, like "x" and "xyz" do. And no, OP doesn't mean the variable modifiers, just the variable names.

Comment: @blurfus I tried to find that option. But, IntelliJ don't have option like anonymous classes to align fields

Comment: hmmm, I thought there was one... let me see what options there are then

Comment: In Group Declarations: do you have the `Align assignments in columns` option enabled? (should be in `Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces (tab)` - or the `Align fields in columns`

Comment: I did try it on my localhost, no dice... maybe you can't w/ OOB IntelliJ - not sure if options like `.editorconfig` will allow for it

Comment: I've raised a new issue at JetBrains issues tracker. Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-309660 for updates